# Помогите в написании алгоритма для генерирования отсортированного массива

Tags: алгоритм

Например, два отсортированных массива

```
a = [1, 4, 5]
b = [3, 5, 7]
```

Необходимо выводить произведения a[i] * b[j].
В итоге должно получиться 3, 5, 7, 12, 15, 20, 25, 28, 35.
Создать третий массив и в нем сортировать не подходит, так как массивы могут быть до 6000 элементов, а время не резиновое.

Comment: Вам нужно в реальном времени это делать? Однократно ну секунд 10 на медленном питоне на этой уйдёт, это немного.

Comment: Если можете сначала быстро сделать, а потом сортировать, то обязательно сортируйте. Помните, если все данные не влезают в пару десятков регистров, то современный компьютер на самом деле быстро работает только с последовательными данными в памяти

Answer (score 6):

Сравним сортировку и порождение массива без сортировки.

Сортировка устроена так (вариант заимствован у [extrn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324712/extrn)):

```
a = [1, 4, 5]
b = [3, 5, 7]
print(*sorted(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, itertools.product(a, b)))
```

> ```
> 3 5 7 12 15 20 25 28 35
> ```

Строится декартово произведение списков, которое превращается в произведения, которые сортируются.

Вариант без сортировки использует кучу:

```
a = [1, 4, 5]
b = [3, 5, 7]
seq = lambda f: (ai * f for ai in a)
print(*heapq.merge(*(seq(bi) for bi in b)))
```

> ```
> 3 5 7 12 15 20 25 28 35
> ```

Функция `seq` создаёт генераторы возрастающих последовательнотей, которые затем смешиваются в одну последовательность.

Сравним потребительские свойства обоих вариантов. Сортировка:

```
n = 6000
a = tuple(range(1, n + 1))
b = tuple(range(n + 1, 2 * n + 1))
print(sum(sorted(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, itertools.product(a, b)))))
```

> 972216009000000

Куча:

```
n = 6000
a = tuple(range(1, n + 1))
b = tuple(range(n + 1, 2 * n + 1))
seq = lambda f: (ai * f for ai in a)
print(sum(heapq.merge(*(seq(bi) for bi in b))))
```

> 972216009000000

На моём компьютере сортировка выполняется за 10.4с и потребляет 1.4Gb памяти. Куча работает 41.3с и требует 9.4Mb памяти. В четыре раза медленнее и в 140 (!) раз меньше памяти. В случае с сортировкой надо ждать пока будет создан и отсортирован массив целиком. Куча начинает выдавать элементы немедленно.

Если памяти хватает - сортируйте, если нет - можно разменять скорость на память.

Comment: Можно также сравнить с `data = numpy.outer(a, b).ravel(); data.sort(kind='stable')`. Разумеется, числа получатся ограниченного диапазона, но скорость будет пропорционально выше, а потребление памяти - ниже.

Comment: Мда, насколько в питоне все запущено :) У меня машина слабее, программа с сортировкой идет 16.6с, но вот на С++ то же счастье выполняется за 2 секунды и 150 мегабайт...

Comment: @Harry А вариант с `numpy`? В Google Colab он тоже порядка 2с работает, ибо там внутри чистый C++ ;)

Comment: @CrazyElf Я в нем не настолько "копенгаген", чтоб самому написать. Дайте код, проверю :)

Comment: @Harry Так @extrn весь код в комментарии привёл, нужно только `import numpy` ещё сделать перед этим. Инициализацию данных из ответа можно взять, хотя инициализация через `numpy.arange` быстрее будет, но тут это не суть важно.

Comment: @Harry Добавил свой ответ с кодом, я его всё-равно писал, не пропадать же

Answer (score 6):

Если использовать библиотеку `Numpy`, то будет практически также быстро, как на `C++`, потому что внутри у этой библиотеки тоже `C++`:

```
%%time
import numpy as np
n = 6000
a = np.arange(1, n + 1)
b = np.arange(n + 1, 2 * n + 1)
c = np.multiply.outer(a, b).ravel()
c.sort(kind='stable')
print(c.sum())
```

Вывод:

```
972216009000000
CPU times: user 1.65 s, sys: 1.29 ms, total: 1.65 s
Wall time: 1.67 s
```

Да, в `Numpy` целые числа ограничены, в отличие от бесконечных целых самого питона, но в остальном `Numpy` ничем не хуже родного кода на `C++`, а то и лучше, потому что много готовых функций под самые разные задачи.

P.S. Если у кого-то будет переполнение, можно жёстко прописать побольше тип данных:

```
a = np.arange(1, n + 1, dtype=np.int64)
b = np.arange(n + 1, 2 * n + 1, dtype=np.int64)
```

Comment: Что у меня может быть не так? Выводит -1378057152... Python3 из комплекта Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @Harry Хм, а `print(c.dtype)` что говорит? Может под виндой `int32` вместо `int64` по умолчанию, тогда в `arange` надо добавить параметр `dtype=np.int64`. Хотя в колабе и с `int32` нет переполнения, только с `int16`.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. Работает 1.5 секунды, быстрее, чем однопоточный, но медленнее многопоточного вариантов на С++. Так что окончательно доказано, что боязнь автора вопроса необоснованная...

Comment: Вдогонку - https://ideone.com/S0JBDx vs https://ideone.com/msk6ZY - а тут С++ немного, но быстрее. Вобщем, тут уже, видимо, начинает зависеть от оптимизатора и т.п. фокусов...

Comment: @Harry В питоне можно ещё c `Numba` побаловаться, там многопоточная оптимизация, но припинать её не так просто бывает, особенно поверх `Numpy`.

Answer (score 3):

Гм, поскольку о Python говорит только массив в квадратных скобках, а метки такой нет...

На С++ это [отрабатывает достаточно быстро](https://ideone.com/msk6ZY)

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(36000000);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6000; ++i)
        for(int j = 6001; j <= 12000; ++j)
            v.push_back(i*j);
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    long long s = 0;
    for(int x: v) s += x;
    cout << s;
}
```

Ну, а если `sort(execution::par,v.begin(),v.end());`, то, сами понимаете... :)