# Когда выгоднее устойчивая сортировка?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, оптимизация, производительность

Навеяно [вот этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1330504/195342).

Мое решение

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v(36000000);
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 1;    i <= 6000; ++i)
        for(int j = 6001; j <= 12000; ++j)
            v[k++] = i*j;
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    long long s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 36000000; ++i) s += v[i];
    cout << s;
}
```

Работало примерно так же, как и лучшее на Python, но чуть медленнее. На моей машине все это считало примерно 2,04±0,01 секунды. Ну не может же быть, чтоб С++ уступал Python'у :) — и я начал по всякому этот код пытаться ускорить.

Оптимизировать не удавалось, все упиралось в `sort`. С горя заменил его на `stable_sort` — посмотреть, что будет, и — о чудо! — время упало до 1,30±0,03 секунды.

Вроде бы всегда говорилось, что в силу большей сложности `stable_sort` (и не только алгоритмической, каковая равна *O(N·log(N)<sup>2</sup>)*) в общем случае работает хуже `sort`. Но, как выясняется, это как минимум не всегда так? Я понимаю, что константа может быть очень разной :), но когда она меньше, чем константа в `sort`?

Под G++ проверено — разница чуть другая, но в целом то же самое: [1](https://ideone.com/LiCFce) и [2](https://ideone.com/b4ERBJ).

Никто в этом не копался, не может дать свои комментарии, что и когда *эффективнее* применять, если устраивает и та, и другая функциональность?

Visual C++ 2019, Windows 10

Comment: если дочитать описание stable_sort, то там есть приписка, что если памяти достаточно, то сложность сильно улучшается до `O(N*log(N))`. я проверил мой gcc и там очень таки `n*logn`

Comment: @KoVadim Даже если асимптотическая сложность та же, то все равно константа — из общих соображений — должна быть большей, так как требований удовлетворяется больше — выходной массив не просто отсортирован, но и отсортирован так, что ....... Значит, время работы должно быть бóльшим, нет?

Comment: для этого нужно посмотреть в середину этих функций. Очень часто они имеют обработку всяких краевых случаев. Например, std::sort может использовать обычную сортировку вместо быстрой на маленьких массивах.

Comment: stable_sort обычно использует сортировку слиянием,  а эта сортировка  есть объединение  под диапазонов, которые  легче сортировать. В вашем примере  одни сортированные диапазоны, поэтому  самая быстрая сортировка для них это сортировка слиянием. Если  последовательность можно разбить на быстро сортируемые  или уже отсортированные под последовательности , то эффективнее сортировка слиянием(или stable_sort), тем более, если логика упорядочения в этих диапазонах одинакова(в вашем примере в одном диапазоне  значения просто  несколько раз больше значений  предыдущего диапазона(...

Comment: `Ну не может же быть, чтоб С++ уступал Python'у :) — и я начал по всякому этот код пытаться ускорить` учитывая, что под капом у питона все равно не питон:) ответ очевиден. Просто для одной функции совпало, что данные и алгоритм хорошо подошли друг-дружке.

Comment: и отвечая на вопрос, поставленный в вопросе, как всегда нужно экспериментировать, смотреть, бенчмаркать. Каждые реализации функций сортировок могут включать свои особенности, которые могут давать разнообразные спецэффекты. Да, можно взять какую то конкретную реализацию, какой то конкретный набор данный и доказать, почему такие результаты. Но в общем случае - никак.

Comment: @KoVadim Понятно, что под капотом — С/С++, но именно поэтому код на чистом С/С++ должен быть *не хуже* по производительности. Что до *конкретных* наборов — опять же это банальный совет, но я надеялся что есть какие-то эмпирические rule of thumbs, которые можно использовать при выборе метода сортировки.

Comment: очень распространённое заблуждение. А что такое "не хуже"? всегда быстрее по времени? или можно медленнее, но на 10%, но всегда, но медленнее? Вот в джаве этот трюк активно используется для затуманивания пользователей. виртуальная машина профайлит налету и для конкретных данных дает достаточно хорошие результаты. Питон может это же.

Comment: А может тут не в асимптотеке с константой дело, а в том, как сформированы конкретные значения?

Comment: @Qwertiy Очевидно, что константа зависит не только от реализации, но и от того, что сортируют. (Вопрос на засыпку — от чего сильнее всего зависит КПД печки? :)) Вот я и хочу получить ответ. Например, для сортировки со, скажем, уже отсортированными кусками лучше использовать `sttable`, а для строк разного размера - `sort` (понятно, что это не реальный совет), словом, какие-то эмпирические советы.

Comment: Кстати, вот три варианта результатов — https://ideone.com/4gkWfB. А вот в VC++ 2019 во всех трех случаях `stable_sort` бьет `sort`... Плохая реализация?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Все лучшие алгоритмы сортировки имеют сложность `O(N * log(N))`. Python оказался быстрее потому что использует TimSort, а он работает очень быстро когда массив состоит из отсортированых кусков. Именно такой массив и получается в приведенном двойном цикле.

`std::sort` обычно использует QuickSort на большим массивах. Эта сортировка никак не использует тот факт, что части массива уже отсортированы, на первой же итерации он сломает структуру массива.

`std::stable_sort` обычно использует MergeSort, который требует `O(n)` дополнительной памяти в отличии от QuickSort. Именно из-за дополнительной памяти по умолчанию используют нестабильную сортировку.

Возможно внутри С++ имплементаций MergeSort используется оптимизация, которая проверяет а является ли подмассив уже отсортированным. В таком случае может не применятся InsertionSort на маленьких подмассивах (проверка на то что подмассив уже отсортирован занимает `O(n)`, а InsertionSort занимает `O(n^2)` времени).

Все 3 сортировки (TimSort, QuickSort, MergeSort) используют внутри сортировку вставками если размер подмассива меньше какой-то длины.

Бенчмарк для сравнения `sort` и `stable_sort` предоставлен [@wololo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/262953/wololo) и немного доделан мной:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int rand(int bits)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (bits)
    {
        int add = bits >= 15 ? 15 : bits;
        result = (result << add) | (rand() & ((1 << add) - 1));
        bits -= add;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<int> vect_type;
    const unsigned long vect_size = 50000000;
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<vect_type::size_type>::max() >= vect_size);

    std::vector<int> vect(vect_size), vect_stable(vect_size);

    for (int bits = 1; bits <= 31; bits++)
    {
        cout << "bits: " << bits << endl;

        for (vect_type::size_type i = 0; i < vect_size; ++i)
        {
            volatile int rand_val = rand(bits);
            vect[i] = rand_val;
            vect_stable[i] = rand_val;
        }

        {
            std::clock_t begin = std::clock();
            std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());
            std::clock_t end = std::clock();

            cout << "sort: " << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
        }
        {
            std::clock_t begin = std::clock();
            std::stable_sort(vect_stable.begin(), vect_stable.end());
            std::clock_t end = std::clock();

            cout << "stable_sort: " << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
        }

        cout << (vect == vect_stable) << endl;
    }
}
```

Функция `int rand(int bits)` генерирует случайное число длиной `bits` битов. По каким-то причинам длина чисел влияет на скорость сортировок. Вот что получилось у меня (Visual C++ 2019, Windows 10):

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════════════╗
║ bits ║ sort  ║ stable_sort ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║    1 ║ 0.228 ║ 1.14        ║
║    2 ║ 0.381 ║ 1.419       ║
║    3 ║ 0.503 ║ 1.489       ║
║    4 ║ 0.634 ║ 1.618       ║
║    5 ║ 0.807 ║ 1.765       ║
║    6 ║ 0.96  ║ 1.902       ║
║    7 ║ 1.15  ║ 2.043       ║
║    8 ║ 1.319 ║ 2.193       ║
║    9 ║ 1.483 ║ 2.317       ║
║   10 ║ 1.67  ║ 2.452       ║
║   11 ║ 1.847 ║ 2.59        ║
║   12 ║ 2.022 ║ 2.74        ║
║   13 ║ 2.211 ║ 2.88        ║
║   14 ║ 2.398 ║ 2.997       ║
║   15 ║ 2.573 ║ 3.152       ║
║   16 ║ 2.756 ║ 3.279       ║
║   17 ║ 2.942 ║ 3.412       ║
║   18 ║ 3.13  ║ 3.556       ║
║   19 ║ 3.339 ║ 3.681       ║
║   20 ║ 3.567 ║ 3.794       ║
║   21 ║ 3.765 ║ 3.9         ║
║   22 ║ 4.045 ║ 4.092       ║
║   23 ║ 4.262 ║ 4.066       ║
║   24 ║ 4.332 ║ 4.097       ║
║   25 ║ 4.373 ║ 4.105       ║
║   26 ║ 4.408 ║ 4.122       ║
║   27 ║ 4.416 ║ 4.119       ║
║   28 ║ 4.405 ║ 4.121       ║
║   29 ║ 4.407 ║ 4.109       ║
║   30 ║ 4.421 ║ 4.12        ║
║   31 ║ 4.411 ║ 4.122       ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════════════╝
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в самом деле, интересная идея проверить массив перед сортировкой слиянием на упорядоченные подмассивы. Их можно запомнить, применить к остальным сорировку слиянием, а на последнем этапе слить все вместе многопутевым слиянием. Если у кого будет желание попробовать, то интересно было бы ознакомится с результатами

Comment: @avp Это должны быть подмассивы, куда не надо будет ничего втискивать :) — а для такой проверки нужно проверять опять же все имеющиеся данные.

Comment: Вы описали, как работают разные сортировки. Но вопрос был немного в другом — для каких данных лучше использовать `sort`, а для каких — `stable_sort`?

Comment: @Harry, нет, поскольу на последнем этапе делаем заключительное (n-путевое) слияние всех подмассивов. Может быть (требует исследования) можно пойти и дальше, выделять подмассивы до тех пор, пока в них мало инверсий (скажем, 1/100). Мне кажется, что такие массивы будут эффективно упорядочиваться даже простыми вставками

Comment: @avp Гм, звучит логично. Надо подумать/проверить, насколько проверка может замедлить работу (на асимптотику она вроде бы влиять не будет).

Comment: @Harry, кстати, о sort VS stable-sort. Если инверсий много, то sort. Вопрос в том, что такое *много*... Тут, наверное, только эксперименты. (Это как с размером подмассива, когда с сортировки слиянием (или quicksort) переключаемя на вставки. Понятно, что зависит от конкретного компа и данных. Но обычно (основываясь на предыдущих эксперименах) берут пару десятков (но есть известная реализация qsort, когда переключаются при 4))

Comment: @avp Кстати, вот три варианта результатов — https://ideone.com/4gkWfB. А вот в VC++ 2019 во всех трех случаях `stable_sort` бьет `sort`... Плохая реализация?

Comment: @Harry, я не знаю, что за алгоритм сейчас в sort, а что в stable (ни в linux, ни в VC). Прогнал ваш код у себя (g++ 7.5.0, Linux Mint 19.3). Числа похожи (в т.ч. на нескольких запусках), т.е. на random sort тоже быстрее, на остальных stable sort.

Comment: не особо важно, но существует сортировка за O(N log log N) https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0, правда, только для целых чисел

Comment: @Harry в меня нет объяснения почему `stable_sort` быстрее, даже на случайных данных. Попровал ваш бенчмарк с разными размерами массивов, до 500 миллионов, `stable_sort` всегда быстрее. Если так, тогда я не вижу смысла использовать обычный `sort`.

Comment: Есть только одно предположение. MergeSort работает за "чистые" `O(n*log2(n))` (так неправильно говорить, но для простоты). QuickSort получит "чистые" `O(n*log2(n))` только если будет угадывать всегда медиану. Так как угадывание медианы это случайность, то иногда это значение будет далеко от медианы, что увеличивает константу.

Comment: @Zergatul Вот! Вот и у меня это самый главный вопрос :)

Comment: @verybadcoder Для целых чисел теоретически есть даже сортировка за O(n) :)

Comment: @Harry ну это теоретически)

Comment: @verybadcoder Ну, если диапазон небольшой, то очень даже практически...

Comment: @Harry ну да, сортировка подсчетом

Comment: `Как показывают все бенчмарки`. Какие такие «все»? В ответе нет ни одного теста. `std::stable_sort быстрее или на одном уровне с std::sort даже на массиве с полностью случайными данными`. Ну, допустим, [контрпример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94261ed75f904333).

Comment: @wololo спасибо за пример, я обновил ответ, только всё стало ещё запутанней :)

Comment: раньше мы смотрели на бенчмарк @Harry, а там всегда stable_sort побеждал, потому что значения были до 72 миллионов (27 бит). У вашем же примере числа 15-битные.

Comment: Мда, вот уж никогда бы не подумал. По крайней мере для `int` вопрос оказался , с одной стороны, решен, с другой — он вызывает столько вопросов "почему"... :) Спасибо! Ставлю птичку, но если кто-то ответит на "почему", то...

Comment: Хм, действительно, интересная зависимость... Но в своём примере я использовал g++, и числа, возвращаемые `std::rand()`, там [31-битные](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80a7d044bb075b49).

Comment: Да, высказанное ранее предположение про медиану, пока что мне видится наиболее вероятным. Медиана считается приближенно. Из сортируемого массива берётся несколько значений, и на основе этих значений формируется приближенная медиана. Видимо, с ростом количества битов в сортируемых значения, получающаяся выборка оказывается всё менее репрезентативной (это предположение) => приближенная медиана оказывается всё дальше от настоящей => всё больше проседает скорость сортировки.

Comment: @wololo это объясняет изменение скорости нестабильной сортировки, но почему и стабильная становится быстрее?