# Как ускорить сортировку коротких массивов?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, шаблоны-с++, производительность

В проекте часто приходится сортировать массивы с такими характеристиками:

- Размер **2 - 32** (чаще всего 2, 3, 4, 8)
- Упорядочены **случайно**
- Тип хранимых данных **uint32_t**

Стандартная сортировка работает с такими данными достаточно медленно.

Поэтому была написана сортировка Network Sort. Он реализован с помощью частичной специализации. Каждая специализация соответствует определенному размеру массива, который должна сортировать.

Вот минимальная часть кода:

Вспомогательная функция, которая меняет второй элемент с первым, если второй меньше первого.

```
namespace mi { namespace impl {
  template<class ItTy, class PredicateTy>
  void swap_if(ItTy first, ItTy second, PredicateTy predicate) {
    if (predicate(*second, *first)) {
      std::swap(*second, *first);
    }
  }
}}  // namespace mi::impl
```

И реализация сортировки:

```
template<size_t N>
struct NetworkSort;

template<>
struct NetworkSort<30U> {
  public:
    template<class ItTy, class PredicateTy>
    void operator()(ItTy first, ItTy last, PredicateTy predicate) {
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 0u, first + 2u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 4u, first + 6u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 8u, first + 10u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 12u, first + 14u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 16u, first + 18u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 20u, first + 22u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 24u, first + 26u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 0u, first + 4u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 8u, first + 12u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 16u, first + 20u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 24u, first + 28u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 2u, first + 6u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 10u, first + 14u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 18u, first + 22u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 0u, first + 8u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 16u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 2u, first + 10u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 18u, first + 26u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 4u, first + 12u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 20u, first + 28u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 6u, first + 14u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 0u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 2u, first + 18u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 4u, first + 20u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 6u, first + 22u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 8u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 10u, first + 26u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 12u, first + 28u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 10u, first + 20u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 12u, first + 18u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 6u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 26u, first + 28u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 14u, first + 22u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 2u, first + 4u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 8u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 2u, first + 8u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 14u, first + 26u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 4u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 22u, first + 28u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 4u, first + 8u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 10u, first + 12u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 18u, first + 20u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 22u, first + 26u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 6u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 14u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 12u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 20u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 6u, first + 10u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 14u, first + 18u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 6u, first + 8u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 10u, first + 12u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 14u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 18u, first + 20u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 22u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 12u, first + 14u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 16u, first + 18u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 1u, first + 3u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 5u, first + 7u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 9u, first + 11u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 13u, first + 15u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 17u, first + 19u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 21u, first + 23u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 25u, first + 27u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 1u, first + 5u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 9u, first + 13u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 17u, first + 21u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 25u, first + 29u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 3u, first + 7u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 11u, first + 15u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 19u, first + 23u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 1u, first + 9u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 17u, first + 25u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 3u, first + 11u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 19u, first + 27u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 5u, first + 13u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 21u, first + 29u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 15u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 1u, first + 17u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 3u, first + 19u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 5u, first + 21u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 23u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 9u, first + 25u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 11u, first + 27u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 13u, first + 29u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 11u, first + 21u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 13u, first + 19u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 25u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 27u, first + 29u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 15u, first + 23u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 3u, first + 5u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 9u, first + 17u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 3u, first + 9u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 15u, first + 27u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 5u, first + 17u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 23u, first + 29u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 5u, first + 9u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 11u, first + 13u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 19u, first + 21u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 23u, first + 27u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 17u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 15u, first + 25u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 13u, first + 17u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 21u, first + 25u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 11u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 15u, first + 19u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 9u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 11u, first + 13u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 15u, first + 17u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 19u, first + 21u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 23u, first + 25u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 13u, first + 15u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 17u, first + 19u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 0u, first + 1u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 2u, first + 3u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 4u, first + 5u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 6u, first + 7u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 8u, first + 9u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 10u, first + 11u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 12u, first + 13u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 14u, first + 15u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 16u, first + 17u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 18u, first + 19u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 20u, first + 21u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 22u, first + 23u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 24u, first + 25u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 26u, first + 27u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 28u, first + 29u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 1u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 3u, first + 18u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 5u, first + 20u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 22u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 9u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 11u, first + 26u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 13u, first + 28u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 1u, first + 8u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 3u, first + 10u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 5u, first + 12u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 14u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 9u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 11u, first + 18u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 13u, first + 20u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 15u, first + 22u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 17u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 19u, first + 26u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 21u, first + 28u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 1u, first + 4u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 3u, first + 6u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 5u, first + 8u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 10u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 9u, first + 12u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 11u, first + 14u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 13u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 15u, first + 18u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 17u, first + 20u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 19u, first + 22u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 21u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 23u, first + 26u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 25u, first + 28u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 1u, first + 2u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 3u, first + 4u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 5u, first + 6u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 7u, first + 8u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 9u, first + 10u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 11u, first + 12u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 13u, first + 14u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 15u, first + 16u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 17u, first + 18u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 19u, first + 20u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 21u, first + 22u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 23u, first + 24u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 25u, first + 26u, predicate);
      mi::impl::swap_if(first + 27u, first + 28u, predicate);
    }
};
```

Главная функция, может кому пригодится:

```
#define N 30

static void std_sort(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto v = generate_random_vector(state.range(0));

  STD array<int, N> a;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) { a[i] = (rand() % 1000000); }

  for (auto _: state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a[0]);
    std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
  }
}

static void network_sort(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto              v = generate_random_vector(state.range(0));
  MI NetworkSort<N> sorter;

  STD array<int, N> a;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) { a[i] = (rand() % 1000000); }

  for (auto _: state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a[0]);
    sorter(a.begin(), a.end(), STD less<int>{});
  }
}

BENCHMARK(network_sort)->Arg(1);
BENCHMARK(std_sort)->Arg(1);
```

Но почему-то моя реализация работает намного медленнее стандартной сортировки.
Хотя у других, вроде как, получается быстрее: [Тык#1](https://github.com/Vectorized/Static-Sort), [Тык#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786899/fastest-sort-of-fixed-length-6-int-array), [Тык#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790522/very-fast-sorting-of-fixed-length-arrays-using-comparator-networks). Я протестировал их код и он у меня работает медленнее, чем стандартная сортировка.

Вот результаты теста:

```
Run on (4 X 3600 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x4)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x4)
  L2 Unified 256 KiB (x4)
  L3 Unified 6144 KiB (x1)
----------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                Time             CPU   Iterations
----------------------------------------------------------
network_sort/1        94.5 ns         80.2 ns      8960000
std_sort/1            45.8 ns         36.8 ns     18666667
```

Меня смущает то, что количество сравнений у std::sort при длине массива n = 30 составляет примерно n*log2(n) ~ **150** В СРЕДНЕМ случае, а у NetworkSort **170** В ЛЮБОМ случае.

> Хм.. Может оно и не может быстрее работать?

Мне кажется, что компилятор должен оптимизировать этот код так, чтобы элементы массива менялись местами по несколько за раз. И у меня есть уверенность что какой-нибудь GCC так бы и сделал (я использую VS).

Можно как-то ускорить это? Стараться разделить свапы на несколько потоков, наверное, только замедлит этот код, а больше у меня нет идей.

Comment: Я бы на таких мелких размерах попробовал сортировки O(n^2) — в силу простоты они могут отрабатывать быстрее всего...

Comment: А собственно `predicate` не может тормозить, например? Сорри, если тупой вопрос.

Comment: да да, пузырек может порвать очень сильно другие сортировки на таких размерах. Если структура данных известна лучше, то можно использовать сортировку подсчетом, которая будет близка к O(n) (а быстрее сильно-сильно сложнее)

Comment: пузырек рвет до тех пор, пока размер <= 5, потом тормозит сильно(

Comment: даже при 8 пузырек работает. Но это нужно аккуратно бенчмаркать. В некоторых случаях у меня было даже при 12-16.   а пять это потому что 5*5/2 это приблизительно 5* log2(5)? :)

Comment: Нет, это я экспериментальным путем проверил. На пяти элементах одинаковое время

Comment: Очень интересно было бы попробовать отсортировать массив через SIMD. Массив из 32 элементов длиной 32 бита влезет в него полностью и еще останется место для сортировки.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проверка на VC++ для массивов 4,8,16,32 показывает, что вставка и при 16 бьет стандартную сортировку. На g++ — и того круче, при 32 :)

Тут данные для VC++ 2019; полный код и результаты для g++ - см. https://ideone.com/EduCM3

Так что считаю свой совет использовать алгоритм сортировки вставками не просто обоснованным, а и доказанным :)

```
stl sort    : N =  4 : 19972097628447 for   2236 mks
stable sort : N =  4 : 19972097628447 for   2198 mks
Bubble sort : N =  4 : 19972097628447 for   2091 mks
EBubble sort: N =  4 : 19972097628447 for   2242 mks
Insert sort : N =  4 : 19972097628447 for   1792 mks
Select sort : N =  4 : 19972097628447 for   2635 mks


stl sort    : N =  8 : 40006459862344 for   6572 mks
stable sort : N =  8 : 40006459862344 for   6136 mks
Bubble sort : N =  8 : 40006459862344 for   7996 mks
EBubble sort: N =  8 : 40006459862344 for   8875 mks
Insert sort : N =  8 : 40006459862344 for   5301 mks
Select sort : N =  8 : 40006459862344 for   8386 mks


stl sort    : N = 16 : 80077500292087 for  14895 mks
stable sort : N = 16 : 80077500292087 for  13838 mks
Bubble sort : N = 16 : 80077500292087 for  35777 mks
EBubble sort: N = 16 : 80077500292087 for  32958 mks
Insert sort : N = 16 : 80077500292087 for  14141 mks
Select sort : N = 16 : 80077500292087 for  32009 mks


stl sort    : N = 32 : 159981299934791 for  32750 mks
stable sort : N = 32 : 159981299934791 for  33863 mks
Bubble sort : N = 32 : 159981299934791 for 126464 mks
EBubble sort: N = 32 : 159981299934791 for 120895 mks
Insert sort : N = 32 : 159981299934791 for  36501 mks
Select sort : N = 32 : 159981299934791 for 124016 mks
```

**Update**

В связи с новыми данными, что [на сортировку может влиять диапазон значений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1330733/195342) —  вот новые результаты: https://ideone.com/s2pFfu В смысле данного вопроса особых изменений нет.

Comment: Вы недавно задавали вопрос о `stable_sort` — а как обстоят дела с ним? Не хочется делать лишний ответ, может, вы дополните свое эксперимент? Он не окажется быстрее всех?

Comment: @Mikhailo В g++ — только хуже: https://ideone.com/EduCM3  В VC++ результаты практически те же — внес их в ответ.

Comment: А почему такая диспропорция между вопросом и ответом? На вопросе минус и уже два голоса на закрытие, и ответ не принят. Какой-то конфликт мнений?