# Способы поменять значения переменных местами. С++

Tags: c++, переменные

На Python есть следующий способ:

```
a = 5
b = 1
a, b = b, a
```

Попробовал тоже самое на плюсах, не получилось, только так:

```
int a = 5; int b = 10; int c = 0;
c = a; a = b; b = c;
```

Есть ли метод сделать быстрее?

Comment: [XOR-обмен](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR-обмен)

Comment: Вы думаете, что обмен в Python *быстрее*, чем в C+?

Comment: @Harry, ну если в Python даже сортировка [быстрее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1330636)  чем в C++ то, с точки зрения банальной эрудиции, и обмен переменных должен работать быстрее ;) P.S. По-моему автора вопрос интересует не быстродействие, а краткость кода. Т.е. хочется что-то вроде `[a, b] = [b, a];`, а не вот это вот всё: `#include <algorithm> ... using ::std::swap; swap(a, b);`...

Comment: @wololo Ну, там мы, кажется, разобрались, и доброе имя С++ восстановлено. Вопрос там шел о том, почему устойчивая сортировка оказалась быстрее обычной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На счет быстрее не уверен, но компактнее можно. std::swap по итогу реализована ровно так же

```
int a = 57;
int b = 45;
printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
std::swap(a,b);
printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
```

И в качестве дополнительного метода - обмен без использования временной переменной из школьного курса

```
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
```

Comment: `обмен без использования временной переменной`, который на некоторых входных данных может приводить к неопределённому поведению из-за знакового целочисленного переполнения.

Comment: совершенно верно, тем не менее для общего развития полезно и такое знать

Comment: Если хочется без третьей переменной, лучше взять xor swap, который не дает UB никогда.

Comment: Извиняюсь, неправильно выразился. Под "быстрее" я имел ввиду процесс написания кода.

Answer (score 1):

О скорости в Python и плюсах.

```
a = 5
b = 1
for i in range(0,100000000):
    a, b = b, a
print(a,b)
```

Этот код на моей машине выполняется примерно 10 секунд. На VC++2019 при компиляции аналога

```
int a = 5, b = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
{
    int c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
}
cout << a << " " << b;
```

я отключил оптимизацию (иначе результат очевиден :)), так что код скомпилировался в

```
; 20   :     int a = 5, b = 1;

    mov DWORD PTR a$[rsp], 5
    mov DWORD PTR b$[rsp], 1

; 21   :     for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)

    mov DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN4@main
$LN2@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR i$1[rsp]
    inc eax
    mov DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], eax
$LN4@main:
    cmp DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], 100000000       ; 05f5e100H
    jge SHORT $LN3@main

; 22   :     {
; 23   :         int c = a;

    mov eax, DWORD PTR a$[rsp]
    mov DWORD PTR c$2[rsp], eax

; 24   :         a = b;

    mov eax, DWORD PTR b$[rsp]
    mov DWORD PTR a$[rsp], eax

; 25   :         b = c;

    mov eax, DWORD PTR c$2[rsp]
    mov DWORD PTR b$[rsp], eax

; 26   :     }

    jmp SHORT $LN2@main
$LN3@main:

; 27   :     cout << a << " " << b;
```

со временем выполнения порядка 0.25 секунд.

Не всегда то, что записано кратко, быстро.

При том же ключике `/Od` применение `swap`

```
; 23   :         swap(a,b);

    lea rdx, QWORD PTR b$[rsp]
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
    call    ??$swap@H$0A@@std@@YAXAEAH0@Z       ; std::swap<int,0>
```

увеличило время работы примерно вдвое.